# ctl_dir /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/ is not secure at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Net/OpenSSH/Compat/Perl.pm line 123

Tags: perl, perl-module, openssh

I installed Net::OpenSSH::Compat::Perl recently. All the dependencies were installed without any errors. But when I try to login using the following code

```
$linux_ses= Net::OpenSSH::Compat::Perl->new($host);
$linux_ses->login($linux_uname,$linux_pass);
```

I get the following error message:

"ctl_dir /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/ is not secure at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Net/OpenSSH/Compat/Perl.pm line 123."

I am running the script as root and the file permission of /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/ is 700.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions on /root/ could be too loose. Group writeable could mean able to delete a .libnet-openssh-perl/ by someone other than root, which is not a secure situation.

Please check.

Comment: Thanks @edehont. I changed the permissions to 700. I still face the same issue.

Comment: I changed the permissions of  /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/ to 500. It worked. this link -[link](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/45/idpl/16345800/numer/3/nazwa/Net::OpenSSH)  suggests that the file should be writable only by the current user. But it no where mentions that it should not be executable. Can you please provide more insight?

Comment: I got the following error _unable to establish master SSH connection: the authenticity of the target host can't be established; the remote host public key is probably not present on the '~/.ssh/known_hosts' file at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Net/OpenSSH/Compat/Perl.pm line 123.__ . I did SSH using SSH client and since the public key got added, it is working now. Doesn't Net::OpenSSH::Compat::Perl fetch public key of the remote host?

Comment: Directories should be 'executable' (or else you can't search them) but files shouldn't, unless they are executable files.

Comment: Accepting a host fingerprint without asking can be a security risk. Manually fetching the remote key like you did is the right way to go. You can however override the question with the option "StrictHostKeyChecking yes" in the local ssh configuration. When the remote host key changes, you still either will have to import it with a manual ssh session, or remove the old one from known_hosts manually. You can persuade ssh to store host keys in /dev/null, so every host is always considered new. But that is a very dirty trick that I wouldn't recommend.

Comment: thanks a lot! I had made the change in "ssh_config" to blindly add the host key. But will it be a problem once the host key has changed?

Comment: Host keys don't change without a reason. Typically it happens with a fresh install. Ignoring host key changes leave you vulnerable to man in the middle attacks. This topic is becoming a chat, so let's end it here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112343/discussion-between-silentmonk-and-edehont).